# What is the best way to avoid memory leaks when a handler needs BuildContext?

Tags: flutter, dart, memory-leaks

I love Dart and Flutter and garbage collection (GC) works perfectly 99%. However, there are cases when GC cannot recognize that an object is not going to be used any more.

I heard passing context to a closure sometimes may cause a serious memory leak. Should i always avoid it or there are cases when it is ok?
In my case I need to show dialog. Here is the options I see:

1. Stateless widget with closure that stores context:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyCoolButton(
      onTap: () async {
        unawaited(
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => MyDialog(),
          ),
        );
      },        
    );
  }
}
```

2. Stateful widget with a member-handler:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SecondaryControls> createState() => _SecondaryControlsState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  void _openDialog() async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => MyDialog(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyCoolButton(
        onTap: _openDialog,        
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I talked to people around and here is the summary:

1. Yes, passing buildContext to closure is a leak-prone thing: if the closure lives longer than the build context should, a memory leak will happen. And, it can be significant, as the context references the entire widget tree (so, if the context is held by the closure, the entire tree will not be garbage collected when it should).
2. If the closure does not outlive the widget (not the state of widget, that may live much longer), it is ok to pass the context to the closure.
3. In my concrete situation the closure does not outlive the widget, so both options are valid and stateless is preferable as it is more concise.

Comment: Here is some extra information about how using large objects (such as BuildContext) in closures can lead to memory leaks, and how to prevent it: [https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/memory#memory-leaks-happen-in-dart](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/memory#memory-leaks-happen-in-dart)

Answer (score 1):

> I know passing context to closure can cause a serious memory leak.

This is a misunderstanding.

You should always avoid saving/caching `BuildContext` as it might cause a situation where the context is detached at the time it is needed. Passing a context is pretty common. Say you build a `Widget` that takes in a `WidgetBuilder` as a parameter, that builder function/closure will be called with the context from the `Widget`s `build` method. Passing in a context into `showDialog` is unavoidable but also not an issue.

Generally, in code bases I work in, it's forbidden to pass a build context to a constructor. It is *always* preferred to pass in the thing the build context is used to access.

Comment: The problem is that `showDialog` is a framework method, so I cannot modify it to take something less than BuildContext.

Comment: But why would you need to take something "less than a BuildContext"? As I said, it's unavoidable but also not an issue.

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing wrong with passing a BuildContext to functions in this manner, otherwise showDialog wouldn't have been designed like that.

There is also no such thing as a memory leak in Dart, the garbage collector can handle closures and circular references just fine.

Comment: Leaks are still possible.

Comment: Leaks happen if developers are not careful about lifecycle of objects. For example, if you non-intentionally add more and more objects to a long-living stateful widget, your app will crash. And it can be hard to catch (if you pass a build context, that can be huge, to a closure and then save this closure to a state).   See [details](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/exploring-memory-leaks-in-flutter-from-the-rendering-process_597736).

Comment: RenderObjectElements remove their reference to the RenderObject when disposed, so that article is making false or outdated assumptions. Also, their only example of a leak is something that would throw an exception and not a real world example.

Unintentional references to objects (from a long lived asynchronous operation) may consume memory like a leak, but they are not the same as they are still indirectly referenced from a GC root.

The only way for your app to actually leak memory is from a plugin that manages native resources and expects you to call dispose on it.

Comment: Leak memory in Dart is a thing. https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/memory#how-can-memory-leaks-happen-in-dart

Comment: If I understand correctly I think @PixelToast is speaking from a more traditional definition of what a memory leak is in say C or C++ where knowledge that memory has been allocated is lost before that memory is deallocated vs in Dart and other GCed systems where the memory is still referenced, and thus never GCed, but the logic of the application doesn't recognize that it was, will never dereference it, and thus it'll remain and maybe even accumulate through the lifetime of the app